# Change python mro at runtime

Tags: python, class, method-resolution-order

I've found myself in an unusual situation where I need to change the MRO of a class at runtime.

The code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print self.__class__
        print "__init__ A"
        self.hello()

    def hello(self):
        print "A hello"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print "__init__ B"
        self.msg_str = "B"
        self.hello()

    def hello(self):
        print "%s hello" % self.msg_str

a = A()
b = B()
```

As to be expected, this fails as the `__init__` method of A (when called from B) calls B's `hello` which attempts to access an attribute before it exists.

The issue is that I'm constrained in the changes I can make:

- B must subclass A
- A cannot be changed
- Both A and B require a hello method
- B cannot initialise other attributes before calling the super `__init__`

I did solve this conceptually, by changing the MRO at runtime. In brief, during B's `__init__`, but before calling super `__init__`, the MRO would be changed so that A would be searched for methods first, thereby calling A's `hello` instead of B's (and therefore failing).

The issue is that MRO is read only (at class runtime).

Is there another way to implement this ? Or possibly a different solution altogether (that still respects the aforementioned constraints) ?

Comment: Must `B` *actually* subclass `A`, or does it just have to appear as a subclass of `A`?

Comment: @Blender, I'm very sure it must subclass, not just appear to have the same attributes/methods.

Comment: Maybe I should word that differently: do you use any property of `B` being a subclass of `A` other than `issubclass(B, A)` returning `True`?

Comment: I'm unsure, as its a C++ to python package (wxPython) which is pedantic about subclassing.

Comment: Can you explain your exact situation? I think this example may be a little oversimplified.

Comment: Not without making the question overcomplicated. In essence, I need to dictate which methods A will call when called from B (in the case of ``__init__``).

Comment: Can you explain the situation that allows you to set `B.__mro__` before calling the superclass `__init__`, but doesn't allow you to just set `self.msg_str` at that time?

Comment: Such manipulation of MRO is not thread safe, and can result with unexpected behavior

Comment: @BrenBarn, the example isn't perfect. Let's say ``msg_str`` is an object that requires a ``B`` object as a parent and so that can't happen before the super ``__init__``.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The other provided answers are advisable if you are not bound by the constraints mentioned in the question. Otherwise, we need to take a journey into mro hacks and metaclass land.

After some reading, I discovered you can [change the mro](http://pybites.blogspot.com.au/2009/01/mro-magic.html) of a class, using a metaclass.

This however, is at class creation time, not at object creation time. Slight modification is necessary.

The metaclass provides the `mro` method, which we overload, that is called during class creation (the metaclass' `__new__` call) to produce the `__mro__` attribute.

The `__mro__` attribute is not a normal attribute, in that:

1. It is read only
2. It is defined **BEFORE** the metaclass' `__new__` call

However, it appears to be recalculated (using the `mro` method) when a class' base is changed. This forms the basis of the hack.

In brief:

- The subclass (`B`) is created using a metaclass (`change_mro_meta`). This metaclass provides:

  - An overloaded mro method
  - Class methods to change the `__mro__` attribute
  - A class attribute (`change_mro`) to control the mro behaviour

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822850/change-python-mro-at-runtime?noredirect=1#comment31228602_20822850), modifying the mro of a class while in its `__init__` is not thread safe.

The following may disturb some viewers. Viewer discretion is advised.

The hack:

```
class change_mro_meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict):
        out_cls = super(change_mro_meta, cls).__new__(cls, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict)
        out_cls.change_mro = False
        out_cls.hack_mro   = classmethod(cls.hack_mro)
        out_cls.fix_mro    = classmethod(cls.fix_mro)
        out_cls.recalc_mro = classmethod(cls.recalc_mro)
        return out_cls

    @staticmethod
    def hack_mro(cls):
        cls.change_mro = True
        cls.recalc_mro()

    @staticmethod
    def fix_mro(cls):
        cls.change_mro = False
        cls.recalc_mro()

    @staticmethod
    def recalc_mro(cls):
        # Changing a class' base causes __mro__ recalculation
        cls.__bases__  = cls.__bases__ + tuple()

    def mro(cls):
        default_mro = super(change_mro_meta, cls).mro()
        if hasattr(cls, "change_mro") and cls.change_mro:
            return default_mro[1:2] + default_mro
        else:
            return default_mro

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "__init__ A"
        self.hello()

    def hello(self):
        print "A hello"

class B(A):
    __metaclass__ = change_mro_meta
    def __init__(self):
        self.hack_mro()
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.fix_mro()
        print "__init__ B"
        self.msg_str = "B"
        self.hello()

    def hello(self):
        print "%s hello" % self.msg_str

a = A()
b = B()
```

Some notes:

The `hack_mro`, `fix_mro` and `recalc_mro` methods are staticmethods to the metaclass but classmethods to the class. It did this, instead of multiple inheritance, because I wanted to group the mro code together.

The `mro` method itself returns the default ordinarily. Under the hack condition, it appends the second element of the default mro (the immediate parent class) to the mro, thereby causing the parent class to see its own methods first before the subclass'.

I'm unsure of the portability of this hack. Its been tested on 64bit CPython 2.7.3 running on Windows 7 64bit.

Don't worry, I'm sure this won't end up in production code somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

There may be grander solutions but a simple option is to write class B defensively. For example:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print "__init__ B"
        self.msg_str = "B"
        self.hello()

    def hello(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'msg_str'):
            A.hello(self)
            return
        print "%s hello" % self.msg_str
```

A good editor with regex capability could auto-insert appropriate `if not hasattr(self, 'some_flag'):...` lines as the first lines of any methods in B.

Comment: I did consider this, however this would require a large refactoring as (although not shown in the example code) there are quite a number of methods (similar to hello) called in __init__. I'm still holding out for a MRO based hack/solution.

Comment: @dilbert, OK.  I'll be interested to see what mro hacks others can come up with.

Comment: A possible extension of this would be to create a decorator called something like `needs_attr` that is passed the name of an attribute (or a list of attributes) that the method needs.  You could then decorate `hello` with `@needs_attr('msg_str')` and have it handle the delegation to the superclass when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular example, one solution is to give B a *class* attribute to hold a default message:

```
class B(A):

    msg_str = "default msg"

    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print "__init__ B"
        self.msg_str = "B"
        self.hello()

    def hello(self):
        print "%s hello" % self.msg_str
```

Usually this causes confusion, but in this case it might be helpful.  If `B.hello` is called before the instance's `msg_str` is set, it will read the class one.  Once the instance `msg_str` is set, it shadows the class one so that future accesses of `self.msg_str` will see the instance-specific one.

I don't quite understand why you can't set attributes before calling the superclass `__init__`.  Depending on exactly what the underlying situation is, there may be other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to [ask for forgiveness](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print self.__class__
        print "__init__ A"
        self.hello()

    def hello(self):
        print "A hello"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print "__init__ B"
        self.msg_str = "B"
        self.hello()

    def hello(self):
        try:
            print "%s hello" % self.msg_str
        except AttributeError:
            pass  # or whatever else you want

a = A()
b = B()
```

or if you do not want to refactor methods called from **init**:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print self.__class__
        print "__init__ A"
        self.hello()

    def hello(self):
        print "A hello"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            super(B, self).__init__()
        except AttributeError:
            pass  # or whatever else you want
        print "__init__ B"
        self.msg_str = "B"
        self.hello()

    def hello(self):
        print "%s hello" % self.msg_str

a = A()
b = B()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The example code has been greatly simplified, where there are many 'hello' methods, some of which very long. Putting all that code in a try/except block would mask a possibly legitimate exception.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out a solution *which is very specific to the example* you present in your question, and therefor unlikely to help. (But in case it does help at all...)

You can bypass `hello`'s polymorphism by defining it as a class member, instead of a method.

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print "__init__ B"
        self.msg_str = "B"
        self.hello = lambda: print "%s hello" % self.msg_str
        self.hello()
```

(`A` remains unchanged).

This solution will break if:

- you subclass `B` and need to override `hello` in the subclass
- `msg_str` is modified after `__init__` runs
- probably several other
  cases...

Comment: I hadn't thought of that though it doesn't quite 'solve' the problem (the example code doesn't exactly line up with my problem, my apologies). Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to change object's class or rewrite it's mro.

The easiest way is to build a new class with `type` function:

```py
def upgrade_class(obj, old_class, new_class):
    if obj.__class__ is old_class:
        obj.__class__ = new_class
    else:
        mro = obj.__class__.mro()

        def replace(cls):
            if cls is old_class:
                return new_class
            else:
                return cls

        bases = tuple(map(replace, mro[1:]))
        old_base_class = obj.__class__
        new_class = type(old_base_class.__name__, bases, dict(old_base_class.__dict__))
        obj.__class__ = new_class
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's relevant to the specific problem, but it seems to me that changing the MRO on the fly like that could be risky in a concurrent program, and could definitely have issues if any of these objects turn out to be created recursively.

A non-MRO-based solution occurs to me, depending on the nature of the errors this code would have encountered. (Keeping in mind that this is belated. Perhaps somebody else will want a different answer.)

Basically, each hello() method on B would be wrapped in a decorator. Something along the lines of

```
class deferring(object):

    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        # Return an unbound method, or whatever, when called from B.
        if instance is None:
            return self.function.__get__(None, owner)
        else:
            # Indicate that an instance is ready via a flag.
            # May need to tweak this based on the exact problem.
            if hasattr(instance, '_set_up'):
                return self.function.__get__(instance, owner)
            else:
                # Walk the mro manually.
                for cls in owner.__mro__:
                    # Crazy inefficient. Possible to mitigate, but risky.
                    for name, attr in vars(cls).items():
                        if attr is self:
                            break
                    else:
                        continue
                    return getattr(super(cls, instance), name)
                else:
                    raise TypeError
```

If you don't want to go the descriptor route, it's also possible to do something like

```
def deferring(function):
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if hasattr(self, '_set_up'):
            return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            for cls in type(self).__mro__:
                for name, attr in vars(cls).items():
                    if attr is function:
                        break
                else:
                    continue
                return getattr(super(cls, self), name)(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                raise TypeError
    return wrapped
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `self.msg_str = "B"` before `super(B, self).__init__()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not good practice and there's likely better way to solve your use-case. But in general, you can modify the instance `__class__` at runtime, which will modify the mro of the instance (not the class).

For example:

```
class A:
  def f(self):
    print('a')

class B:
  def f(self):
    print('b')

b = B()
b.f()  # b
b.__class__ = A
b.f()  # a
assert type(b) is A
```

With your use-case, it would look like:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hello()

    def hello(self):
        print("A hello")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        parent_init = super().__init__
        # While A.__init__ is called, inheritance is removed
        self.__class__ = A
        parent_init()
        self.__class__ = B  # Restore inheritance

        self.msg_str = "B"

    def hello(self):
        print("%s hello" % self.msg_str)

a = A()  # A hello
b = B()  # A hello  (called in A.__init__)
b.hello()  # B hello
```