# What calls `mro_internal()` in CPython?

Tags: python, cpython, method-resolution-order

I'm looking into how objects come to be in Python, for curiosity more than anything else, and I've come to method resolution order.

In Python, a class `Cl` with base `Ba` when will have the attribute `__mro__`, containing `(<class 'Cl'>, <class 'Ba'>, <class 'object'>)`.  A metaclass can define `mro()`, which will provide a custom tuple for the `__mro__` of child classes to contain when defined.

In C, from what I can understand, this assignment is handled by [`mro_internal`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c393ee858932f79bd6dabf31550f9a53ea90bc68/Objects/typeobject.c#L1937), but I can't see where that's called from.  Even [searching](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mro_internal&type=Code) only turns up a reference to it in a test.

To phrase this as a more runnable question; "how do I redefine the MRO of an instance at runtime?"

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822850/change-python-mro-at-runtime) of any help to the second part of the question. `mro_internal` itself appears to be called from `mro_hierarchy` in the same file, but I don't understand the mechanism enough to say anything useful about it.

Comment: That answer is very good, but modifies `__bases__`, which is an "old-style" class thing only, and therefore Python 2 specific.  `mro_hierarchy` is leading me on the right trail though, I think.

Comment: I could be wrong but: aren't their examples all using `class A(object)` with the inheritance from `object` making it new style?

Comment: Huh, you know what, you're very correct.  I just tried it out and updating `__bases__` and it updated `__mro__` just fine.  It works on the class level, not the instance, but that's unlikely to be workaroundable.  Thanks.