# Multiple inheritance - why does super not follow MRO principle?

Tags: python

Example:

```
class A:
    def test(self):
        print(" test of A called ")
class B(A):
    def test(self):
        print(" test of B called ")
        super().test()
class C(A):
    def test(self):
        print(" test of C called ")
        super().test()
class D(B,C):
    def test(self):
        print(" test of D called ")
        super().test()
obj=D()
obj.test()
```

Output is: D, B, C, A

I was expecting D, B, A as per MRO principle. What change is needed to get output D, B, A?

Comment: It does follow it. Why do you think C should be missed?

Comment: I thought MRO governs left to right order (in this case B, C) and that once it finds the method (in this case found in B) it does not go to the next (so should skip C) - I am confused

Comment: But you called super. Which explicitly finds the next class in the MRO. Read this: [super considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/amp/).

Answer (score 3):

`super` follows the MRO chain, not inheritence chain, when inside a superclass.

So, `super().test()` inside `D.test` calls `B.test`, and the `super().test()` inside `B.test` calls the next `test` in the MRO chain of `D` -- which is `C.test`. And the `super().test()` inside `C.test` eventually calls `A.test`.

So, the `super().test()` inside `B` calls the next super class' `test()` of `D`, which is `B.test`, not of it's own superclass `A.test`.

Comment: how do I change the output to D, B, A?

Comment: @variable use explicit `A.test(self)` in the class B `test` method

Comment: what about if B is an external class that I cannot modify?

Comment: @variable can you change the `C` class?

Comment: Yes but I cannot remove the super as there are other dependencies on that logic

Comment: You certainly can add `if isinstance(self, D):` protection blocks there and conditionally call `A.test(self)` instead of super when applicable. That is simple.

Comment: @variable Without changing anything in B or C it looks *[hacky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822850/change-python-mro-at-runtime)*. Otherwise being explicit is the standard simple way.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there is no reason to expect `C` to be excluded entirely from the MRO chain, so `D B A` is definitely not correct.

As far as the ordering of `D B C A`, the C3 linearization algorithm enforced two constraints:

- Children precede their parents.
- If a class inherits from multiple
  classes, they are kept in the order specified in the tuple of the
  base class.

([source](https://medium.com/technology-nineleaps/python-method-resolution-order-4fd41d2fcc).)

`D B C A` satisfies the two constraints.

You can see the MRO by yourself like so:

```
>>> D.__mro__
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

When all your classes call `super().test()`, this traverses the MRO chain.

Comment: how do I change the output to D, B, A?